# ionic scrolling is too laggy for windows phone 8

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm using Ionic to build a hybrid app for Android and Windows Phone 8.1.

When scrolling, the below code:

```
<ion-content padding="true" scroll="true" direction="y" scrollbar-y="false" scrollbar-x="false" has-bouncing="true">
  <!-- creating many paragraphs -->
  <p ng-repeat="content in contents">{{content}}</p> //many paragraph
</ion-content>
```

is working smoothly in Android, but very laggy in Windows Phone 8.1

I even used overflow-scroll, but it is still too slow.

Please advise me any fix or workaround for this issue.

Thanks in adnvance!

Comment: [Ion Scroll](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionScroll/)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but unfortunately it doesn't help much.

Comment: @haipham23: Im facing the same issue, were to able to find a solution for this?

Comment: @casper123: yes we can, simply by removing position: absolute, overflow:hidden, ect... in body and html tag in ionic.css. However, be noticed that most of directives related to view and scroll such as ion-view will be useless, which should be replaced by div instead. It would require a consideration of time to adapt to Windows Phone. Regards.

Comment: @haipham23: Do you mean I should replace ion-content and ion-view with normal div ? I've only commented overflow: hidden in body tags.. Is there something else I need to do? Can you please provide some specific example?

Comment: @casper123: yes I'm afraid so, at the time this question was asked, Ionic poorly supported WP8. I can only take advance of it's CSS and few of directives. Currently Ionic releases v1.0, which I don't know if it support WP8 better or not.

Comment: @haipham23: Ionic still has poor support for WP and Windows 8 Apps :)

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Is there a good solution on this without changing the whole templates?

Answer (score 1):

This may not be relevant to you, but I had a similar issue. When using the `wp8` platform (e.g. `ionic platform add wp8`) the app seemed to be wrapped in Silverlight and was painfully slow. Pretty unusable.

Changing to a Windows universal app (`ionic platform add windows`) it was much, much better (but still has other problems not relevant to this post).

Comment: Is it possible to deploy an windows universal app to lumia with wp 8.1?

Answer (score 0):

**Use native scrolling.**

Native scrolling can be enabled using `overflow-scroll=”true”` on your `ion-content` or using the `$ionicConfigProvider` to set it globally in current versions of Ionic.

Comment: From the docs it looks like native scrolling is the default though?

Comment: in the new version(1.2) on all except iOS